# share open graph story on facebook on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I need to share course which was traveled by car on Facebook.But creating custom open graph objects are deprecated on facebook,so I decided to do it with fitness.bike object.I need something like this https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t39.2178-6/851557_504281972964839_1538874606_n.png
I have tried old answers here, but most of the objects and methods were depricated.
I have done every prerequisites which were needed for Facebook's Sdk integration with android project.My method is this: `

```
 public void shareOnFb() {
        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
                .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
                .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
                .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
                .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
                .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
                .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
                .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
                .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
                .build();

        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType("fitness.bikes")
                .putObject("fitness:bikes", object)
                .build();
        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
                .setAction(action)
                .build();
        ShareDialog.show(MapFunctionsFragment.this, content);
    }
```

But it's not showing share dialog at all.So my question is how can I implement share method which will help me to draw path between two locations and then share it on my Facebook.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You are never going to be approved to use fitness.bikes if the user doesn't bike

Comment: I just want to publish path which was passed, there is no need to differ whether it was passed by bike or by car.for example if we give polyline to a method and it would just publish it

Comment: I'm just saying you can not use fitness.bikes because that you can only publish if the user biked